# Error running select with concatenated columns in Postgres with JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I want get concatenated citycode-hotelcode pair from the cityHotelData Table.
(citycode and hotelcode are varchar in cityHotelData Table)

When I am running following query using phpPgAdmin it works fine.

```
select citycode || '-' || hotelcode from cityHotelData
```

But when I am running it in java using JDBC it gives following error.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name citycode || '-' || hotelcode was not found in this ResultSet.
```

I am using `PostgreSQL 8.0.26.`

**Java Code :**

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnString,ConnUser,ConnPassword);

public ResultSet executeStatementQuery(String sql) throws Exception {

        this.qry = sql;

        try {
            stmt    = conn.createStatement(); // Statement stmt
            rs      = stmt.executeQuery(sql); //ResultSet rs
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
            closeResultSet();
        } catch (Exception cnfe) {
            closeResultSet();
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rs;
    }
```

Comment: Your error message says `ciycode` and your query says `citycode`. Please cut and paste both query and error to eliminate typos.

Comment: Also, please post your Java code for the JDBC query.

Comment: @ Paul : It is Statement Paul.

Comment: @Simon : It is cityCode. I have mistaken when posting the question. And added the Java Code too.

Comment: "PostgreSQL 8.0.26". Seriously?!? The 8.0 series was first released in 2005, and the final end-of-life release is over 2 years old. You need to plan an urgent upgrade, reading the release notes for 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2, testing your app, and beginning to test the upgrade.

Comment: Also, what version of PgJDBC are you using?

Comment: SQLFiddle uses PgJDBC, and the query works just fine there (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/256b9/1). Need more info. Are you sure you're running the *exact* same statement from JDBC? Replace `this.qry = sql;` with `this.qry = "select citycode || '-' || hotelcode from cityHotelData;"` and re-test.

Comment: @ all :  
Query mentioned above was dyanamically generated one by using the column name, table and condition. The method signature is public HashSet<String> getDataSet(String colm, String table, String cond). I have used vendorid || '-' || hotelcode as the colm. And I tried to get the data by rs.getString(colm).The root cause of the error is it. When tried with rs.getString(1), it worked fine. How stupid I am. Thank for all your support. I'm extremly sorry if I wasted your valuable time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (citycode || '-' || hotelcode) AS cityhotel
FROM cityHotelData
```

**EDIT**:
To exclude any Java issues, try using this Java code:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(
    "SELECT (citycode || '-' || hotelcode) AS cityhotel FROM cityHotelData"
);
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.print("City-hotel code: ");
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
rs.close();
st.close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer mvp mut itfails saying org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name (vendorid || '-' || hotelcode) AS cityhotel was not found in this ResultSet.

Comment: Can you show your Java code which you are using to access database?

Comment: I see some procedure you wrote, but still don't see your SQL statement anywhere

Comment: One more stupid question: is there a chance that column names are in camelCase inside PostgreSQL database? Can you execute exact same statement in psql or pgadmin?

Comment: Is there any chance you're using some truly prehistoric PgJDBC version to match your very old PostgreSQL release? Have you tried a recent PgJDBC to see if this is a query parsing issue?

Comment: Got it bro. 
This is a dyanamically generated query. 
The method signature is public HashSet<String> getDataSet(String colm, String table, String cond).
I use vendorid || '-' || hotelcode as the colm. So I try to get the data by rs.getString(colm).The root cause of the error is it. When tried with rs.getString(1), it worked fine. How stupid I am.

Comment: @NamalFernando The lesson here: Show *all* the code, not just an incomplete subset. Where you have to, write a self-contained test case to demonstrate the problem. You'll usually find the bug while writing the test case.

Comment: @ Craig : Totally Agreed with you! It was my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this problem is happening - it's obviously an issue with the JDBC preparation of the query but we still don't have the full picture without seeing where exactly the query originates and how it's passed into `executeStatementQuery`.

A simple alternative is to use this query:

```
select citycode, hotelcode from cityHotelData
```

Then just concatenate those values with `-` in the java layer instead.